# Enable www in subdomain in Amazon AWS EC2 Server

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subdomain

I have some problems when I want to add www in subdomain. Because subdomain.domain.org works fine but www.subdomain.domain.org.

I connected to my AWS Instance I go to Route53->Hosted zones-->Add Records Set.

Example:

```
domainname.org. A ALIAS www.domainname.org.

domainname.org. NS

domainname.org. SOA

subdomain.domain.org. A ALIAS www.subdomain.domainname.org.

www.subdomain.domainname.org. A MyElasticIP

www.domainname.org. A MyElasticIP
```

Then in my /etc/apache2/sites-available/httpd.conf
I have inserted virtualhosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName domainname.org
   ServerAlias www.domainname.org
   DocumentRoot var/www/html/domainname.org
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.subdomain.domainname.org
   ServerAlias subdomain.domainname.org
   DocumentRoot var/www/html/subdomainname.domainname.org
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access to subdomain.domainname.org URL is ok but www.subdomain.domainname.org URL doesn't work. So I don't know know what I am doing wrong here, please I need some help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: what's the problem? You showed your configuration but not the problem encountered.

Comment: I have edited my post and my problem comes when I try to access to subdomain.domainname.org URL is ok but www.subdomain.domainname.org URL doesn't work or is not enabled.